# ReCaptcha and AJAX API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I'm trying to display ReCaptcha image through its AJAX API. I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) documentation and [this demo](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax). I still fail in creating a fiddle that works... I added jsfiddle.net as allowed referer to my APIs.

I can't understand what's wrong with **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/sL3w1ac6/)** fiddle!

Console says "`showRecaptcha is not defined`".

```
function showRecaptcha() {
    Recaptcha.create("PUBLIC_APIs", 'captchadiv', {
        tabindex: 1,
        theme: "clean",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `Frameworks and Extensions` on jsfiddle, you need to change `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>` - otherwise the javascript is loaded after the button is, and references a then-non-existent function.

After that, the showRecaptcha() function definitely runs, but no captcha is shown. The only thing I can think of is that, as per [this page](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#createsite):

> Your reCAPTCHA key is restricted to the specified domains, and any subdomains for additional security. A key for foo.com works on test.foo.com.

your public key won't work for jsfiddle.net. I *assume* therefore that if you used this code (having generated a key for your domain) on your own web-page, it would work.

Comment: Uhm.. this is giving me a hard time.. I set up the script on my (allowed) domain.. still nothing: http://romabbandonata.org/test2.html

Here's the console: http://romabbandonata.org/recaptcha.png

Comment: Ok, it's working now. I created a new API with just my domain (without jsfiddle) and now works. Probably they have like a ban on jsfiddle!